# Cloudant DB query batch reading in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, cloudant

I am currently trying to do a batch reading of docs from Cloudant DB. By far, I have done batch reading in JavaScript. However, I am trying to do in C#, which is different.

This is what I've done in JavaScript, and can it be done in C#?

```
db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    attachments: true,
    startkey: 'receipt',
    endkey: 'receipt\uffff'
}).then(function (result) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, the main ones are probably:

1. use a third party C# library like [MyCouch](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch)
2. use C#'s [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to make calls against the [Cloudant API](https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html)
3. use a C# generic rest library such as [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org) to make calls against the [Cloudant API](https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html)

Here is a snippet from MyCouch:

---

> **System views**
>
> If you want to consume one of the built-in CouchDb system views, use the QueryViewRequest constructor with one argument. Here's a sample of consuming the view all_docs:
>
> ```
> var query = new QueryViewRequest("_all_docs");
> var response = await client.Views.QueryAsync<dynamic>(query);
> ```
>
> Source: https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/wiki/documentation#system-views

---